# Getting float values while reading Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, data-analysis

I have Sr.no columns in my csv file witch contain all integer values but will reading it as pandas data frame some integer values are converted into float why?

[I have Data set contain following records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jNuY.png)

[When i load it as Data Frame it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QN4q.png)

[These are n th records of same data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNwAv.png)

[But this time in Data Frame SR.NO column it is showing float values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVAb0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is type domination. 
Check this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))


    A   B
0   1   2
1   3   4  <---- ALL INTEGERS
```

and:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))

    A   B
0   NaN 6
1   7.0 8 <-- NOT INTEGER
```

You can see, 7 -> 7.0. 
And more:

```
df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

    A   B
0   1.0 2
1   3.0 4
2   NaN 6
3   7.0 8
```

Pandas automaticly define a column's type. 
For change this, use `pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'PUT_COL_NAME_HERE': PUT_TYPE_HERE})` or `pd.astype()`

Comment: Great i got it Thank you